# What happens without same-origin-policy?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I know that we can get child or parent iframe document, then modify the dom tree maliciously without same-origin-policy. And Cookie need to be set a domain.

And I read an Article [Why is the same origin policy so important?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).
Here is the part confused me.

> Assume you are logged into Facebook and visit a malicious website in another browser tab. Without the same origin policy JavaScript on that website could do anything to your Facebook account that you are allowed to do. For example read private messages, post status updates, analyse the HTML DOM-tree after you entered your password before submitting the form.

How to do that? I mean attack another browser tab and get its document.

Comment: You simpy don't. We don't suggest how to "hack" websites. By the way, most website today use the same-origin policy

Comment: I just wanna know why we need same-origin-policy. The quote part make me shock, how could do that.

Comment: @Filnor — No website uses the same origin policy, at least no explicitly. The same origin policy is implemented by **browsers**.

Comment: @Quentin Right, that was a fault on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do that? I mean attack another browser tab and get its document.

You can't. The Same Origin Policy exists! That quote describes what could happen if it didn't.